# Issues with phalcon dev tools

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm new to phalcon and I'm having issues with phalcon dev tool commands.

When I type `phalcon serve` I get the following error.

```
Phalcon DevTools (4.1.2)

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Phalcon\Mvc\User\Component' not found in /opt/phalcon-devtools/scripts/Phalcon/Utils/SystemInfo.php on line 36
```

I looked for answers but couldn't find much. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ```Phalcon\Mvc\User\Component``` was removed in phalcon 4. we need more info run ```phalcon i``` and paste it

Comment: Please share more details, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I did not install phalconphp dev tools properly in the first place. I had multiple versions of php installed on my machine. So I uninstalled all unwanted versions of php and stuck with php7.2 and reinstalled phalcon and the dev-tools and everything worked fine.

Leaving it out there for someone in the future.